# How can I let through location updates after a specified delta from a last value using Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Imagine a navigation app which draws the user's current location and a polyline (that thing that shows you where to drive) to the target destination. Which means there should be two event streams, one for location updates, and one for newly calculated polyline based on the location updates.

The problem is that it's computationaly expensive to draw the polyline, so I only want to do it after the user has moved a certain distance from the last point where it was calculated.

Here's how it should work:

1. RED - user moves a small distance, nothing happens
2. BLUE - user moves out of the GREEN circle, which is a distance from the original point when the directions were calculated, and as a result new directions are calculated and a new ORANGE radius is set

[image: navigation]

**The problem I have here is that I don't know how to *carry over* the next computation. I guess it would require some sort of fold, but I'm not sure how to express that in Rx.**

It should look something like this (the two arguments in where are meant as some kind of tuple).

```
locationUpdates.Where((previous, current) => IsFarEnough(previous, current))
               .SomethingThatPutsCurrentBackIntoTheCondition()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observable.Scan is the easiest way to fold or compare current and previous items. [I blogged on this here with some nice diagrams.](http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=213) Here is the code from that article:

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<TSource, TSource>>
    PairWithPrevious<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Scan(
        Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
        (acc, current) => Tuple.Create(acc.Item2, current));
}
```

And the unit test for it:

```
public class PairWithPreviousTests : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Works()
    {
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = Observable.Range(1, 3);

        var results = testScheduler.Start(
            () => source.PairWithPrevious());

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext(Subscribed, Tuple.Create(0, 1)),
            OnNext(Subscribed, Tuple.Create(1, 2)),
            OnNext(Subscribed, Tuple.Create(2, 3)),
            OnCompleted<Tuple<int, int>>(Subscribed));
    }
}
```

You should be able to hack on this to see how to use Scan to carry forward what you need.